# Display a checkmark symbol

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer

I have to display a checkmark symbol on my web page for indicating as valid entries.

I do that by using HTML decimal code &#10003;

But this code is not being supported by IEv 11.0.38.

It works for chrome,firefox and older IE versions

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can use font-awesome library,then this would be very easy.
Checkout
[Fontawesome icons library](http://fontawesome.io/)
and
[Check icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/check/).

Thank you